# Falha na conexão com IBM Language Translation através do PHP cURL

Tags: php, json, libcurl, request

Eu estou com um problema que não consigo resolver. Basicamente eu preciso traduzir uma string em **Português** para **Inglês**. Este é o código que eu consegui desenvolver:

```
<?php
    class CtrlTranslate{
        public function translate($text) {
            $url = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translation/api";

            $user = "[user]";
            $password = "[password]";

            $post_args = array(
                'model_id' => 'pt-en',
                'text' => $text
            );

            $handle = curl_init($url);
            $header_args = array(

                'Content-Type: text/plain',
                'Accept: application/json'
            );

            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_args);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_args);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.":".$password);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response = curl_exec($handle);
            $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
            curl_close($handle);

            return $responseDecoded;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Poderia traduzir sua pergunta? Note que está no Stack Overflow em Português.

Comment: Opa, desculpas amigo.

Comment: Eu estou com um problema que não consigo resolver. Basicamente eu preciso traduzir um texto do Português para Inglês. Este é o código que eu consegui fazer.

Comment: Use o [edit] para traduzir a pergunta